# Передача параметров сигнала в лямбду

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Имеем в наличии такой коннект

```
connect(
   task->get_reply(), 
   SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), 
   task, 
   SLOT(on_progress(qint64, qint64))
);
```

Каким образом его переписать, чтобы вместо слота была лямбда, принимающая два параметра сигнала (основной вопрос как эти параметры захватить)

```
connect(
   task->get_reply(), 
   &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, 
   [=](???){ task->on_progress(???); }
);
```

Comment: `[=](qint64 a, qint64 b){ task->on_progress(a, b); }` ?

Comment: @да, похоже на то) оформите ответом, и заодно, можно ли принять по ссылке?

Comment: принять по ссылке аргументы? или захват лямбды? хотя, не важно. можно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connect(task->get_reply(), &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress,
    [=](qint64 first_arg, qint64 second_arg){
        task->on_progress(first_arg, second_arg);
    });
```

---

```
int external_state = 0;
connect(task->get_reply(), &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress,
    [&external_state](qint64 first_arg, qint64 second_arg){
        task->on_progress(first_arg, second_arg);
    });
```

---

```
connect(task->get_reply(), &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress,
    [=](qint64&& first_arg, qint64& second_arg){
        task->on_progress(std::move(first_arg), second_arg);
    });
```

Comment: спасибо, по ссылке ругается, пойду читать дальше)

Comment: немного дополню, для приема по ссылке, ссылка должна быть константной, вот так: `[=](const qint64& val1, const qint64& val2){ task->on_progress_f(val1, val2); }`

Comment: @goldstar_labs, зависит от контекста применения. если вы собираетесь отправлять временные объекты, например `foo(10, 20)`, тогда квалификатор `const` необходим, если же ссылка будет изменяться в процессе выполнения функции, например `qint64 a; foo(a, a);` тогда квалификатор `const` не нужен.